# How to sort two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this items table.

SELECT * FROM items order by `order`;

**Returned Data' s:**

```
| itemID  |   order  | description |    date_ordered       |
|   1     |    1     |   Apple     |  2016-05-26 08:00:00  |
|   2     |    1     |   Banana    |  2016-05-22 10:00:00  |
|   3     |    2     |   Cocoa     |  2016-05-29 08:00:00  |
|   4     |    3     |   Lychee    |  2016-05-30 12:00:00  |
```

**Expected output:**

```
| itemID  |   order  | description |    date_ordered       |
|   1     |    1     |   Apple     |  2016-05-26 08:00:00  |
|   3     |    2     |   Cocoa     |  2016-05-29 08:00:00  |
|   4     |    3     |   Lychee    |  2016-05-30 12:00:00  |
|   2     |    1     |   Banana    |  2016-05-22 10:00:00  | <-- This is expired
```

I'm stuck on order by. Maybe someone can help me with this. I don't know some filters in mysql just basics.

New added items should go at the top of the query if old it must go at the bottom.

Comment: What is the condition to check if it is expired?

Comment: @pseudoAJ the current date. But I have in my mind is it okay to have new column `isNew` ? if new = 1 else 0?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Order? Filter results? Which criteria precisely? What have you tried?

Comment: By the way it's rarely a good idea to name a column with a reserved word.

Comment: Yeah, you can have one such column and use it as second column to sort the results.

Comment: @Arcesilas I want to show all the results and reorder them not filter.

Comment: Which two columns do you want to sort by?

Comment: @dchayka the date_ordered and order.

Comment: @aldrin27 ASC or DESC? Please add SQL query you've tried so far.

Comment: Quote: "*I don't know some filters*". But you don't want to filter. Again: What do you ***exactly*** want to do?

Comment: @dchayka `SELECT * FROM items order by 'order' ASC, date_ordered DESC` but still wrong output.

Comment: @Arcesilas I want to reorder them just as the expected output. Because my mysql skills is just basics.

Comment: The output does not let us know HOW to get to it. There could be many ways to get the same output for this very specific case but would give something wrong in other cases. Tell us HOW you want to order.

Comment: You should tell us the logic what you want, `order` keyword actually does not get your expected result.

Comment: For example: I have duplicate data in order column the newly item will go at the beginning else if old it will go at the bottom. Just for the duplicates.

Comment: I'm afraid I understand... I suspect an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I have to ask: What do you really want to do, not considering the solution you try to implement. What are your needs, how will you use this result?

Comment: @Arcesilas I don't know how to explain but the results should be as my expected output. I think the reordering is in one table only?

Comment: Do you mean "in one query" instead?

Comment: @Arcesilas Yes. But if you have other I will gladly use that.

Comment: I mentionned [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because I think you're not doing it the right way. But it's really not easy to guess, since you don't provide many details about what you actually want to do and for what needs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you may try this:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY (date_ordered < now()), `order`;
```

When "*ordering by comparison*", the result is "*split*" in two. Then you can order with the criteria of your choice. The comparison must be the first criterion, though.

Comment: Omg. It work. Thank you so much for the help. Earlier i just did `ORDER BY 'order' ASC, 'date_ordered' DESC`

Answer (score 1):

@Arcesilas's answer is definitely right, but in case of new order is before `now()`,  just in case.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3863e/8)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE items
    (`itemID` int, `order` int, `description` varchar(6), `date_ordered` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO items
    (`itemID`, `order`, `description`, `date_ordered`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Apple', '2016-05-26 08:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 'Banana', '2016-05-22 10:00:00'),
    (3, 2, 'Cocoa', '2016-05-29 08:00:00'),
    (4, 3, 'Lychee', '2016-05-30 12:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY items.`order`) items
JOIN (
  SELECT `order`, max(date_ordered) AS date_ordered FROM items GROUP BY `order`
) a ON a.`order` = items.`order` AND  a.date_ordered = items.date_ordered
UNION
SELECT items.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY items.`order`) items
JOIN (
  SELECT `order`, max(date_ordered) AS date_ordered FROM items GROUP BY `order`
) a ON a.`order` = items.`order` AND  a.date_ordered <> items.date_ordered
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3863e/8/0)**:

```
| itemID | order | description |          date_ordered |
|--------|-------|-------------|-----------------------|
|      1 |     1 |       Apple | May, 26 2016 08:00:00 |
|      3 |     2 |       Cocoa | May, 29 2016 08:00:00 |
|      4 |     3 |      Lychee | May, 30 2016 12:00:00 |
|      2 |     1 |      Banana | May, 22 2016 10:00:00 |
```